# How to use rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys!
I'm beginner about ros.

Now I installed ros-jade-ros-base on raspberrypi 2(OS raspbian jessie).

I wanna use hector-slam and I could install it.
but I cannot install Rviz .

I tryed install  "rosdep install rviz"
but "Erro: Rosdep cannot find all reqired resources to answer your query
Missing resource rviz
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/jade/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/jade/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/jade/stacks"
was displayed.

Please help for solving this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226045/how-to-use-rviz/) by [yoneyama1027](https://answers.ros.org/users/25796/yoneyama1027/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try to run : `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-rviz` before you run rosdep install rviz ?
[Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/35741/what-is-this-rosdep-error/) , the error is similar to yours. Look at the first answer "*rosdep is a tool for installing system dependencies for source packages. It does not install the source for you*". It means that you need to install rviz before you will run `rosdep install rviz`.

I advice you:

1. to understand what [rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep) is
2. to check the paths (if the error said that rosdep cant find the resources , you need check them yourself. Maybe, you didnt install ros)
3. to open your terminal and run `cd` and `source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash`
4. to run `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-rviz`

---

Originally posted by [dyupleks](https://answers.ros.org/users/22089/dyupleks/) with karma: 200 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yoneyama1027](https://answers.ros.org/users/25796/yoneyama1027/) on 2016-02-08**:
thank you your kindness.
i tryed "sudo apt-get install ros-jade-rviz"
but "E Unable to correct problems, you have broken packages." was displayed.